# Correct pronunciation of「ひ」

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

I used to pronounce it as **"Hi"** but recently i paid keen attention to natives speaking words like **「広い」、「低い」** and I find out they pronounce it as somewhat **"che"** but when i try to say **"che"** what comes out of my mouth is **「し」("shi")**, so please help me out... I really wanna sound native.

Comment: I think the answers to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1437/1628) answer your question. Please edit your question to clarify in case they don't.