# Is my name, Yurishiko, a Japanese name?

Tags: names

I am Filipino with Japanese blood and ancestry. I don't know how much Japanese is in my blood but when I was born, my mother named me Yurishiko. I just wanted to know if my name is Japanese as it sounds a little unusual. I did not find any other Japanese people online with the same name as me. Is Yurishiko a Japanese name?

Comment: It has a very Japanese sound to it, but I don't know if it's an actual Japanese name,

Comment: 「~~[彦]{ひこ}」(~~hiko), eg [百合彦]{ゆりひこ} (Yurihiko) would be a Japanese male name, but I'm not sure about 「~~しこ」(~~shiko)...   (Does/Did your mother speak Japanese, by the way?)

Comment: My mother was taught Japanese when she was very young but over time, she had forgotten about it especially since she was growing up in the Philippines. She told me she had gotten my name from a name book with Japanese names on it. She might have read my name differently. It would be disappointing if my name didnt really exist at all in Japan. Just a thought.

Comment: I asked because I thought maybe your mother spoke Edo/Tokyo dialect and pronounced ひ(hi) as し(shi). It is known that Edo/Tokyo dialect speakers pronounced ひ as し. So.. your mother saw ゆりひこ in the book and pronounced it as ゆりしこ, maaaybe??

Comment: @yurushiko I wonder if it could be some kind of hybrid of standard name kanji+individually selected kanji, like 許子 ('forgiving child'). I don't know if your mother ever told you if the name had a meaning - if so, that might help identify the kanji in it. By the way, is it ok to ask if you are male or female?

Comment: @YurishikoA. Are you male? That would help us narrow things down.

Comment: I am female. Sorry, I should have clarified that earlier. Also, my mother once mentioned that y name meant "joy". But in my primary school days, a Japanese teacher had visited the philippines and my classmates were curious to ask what my name meant. The teacher said that it meant, "young flower". So it may be either of those, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

As @AeonAkechi says, the name definitely has a Japanese ring to it.

However, *Yurishiko* doesn't seem to be a standard romanization of a common Japanese name, as ゆりしこ as a name is very uncommon (if it exists at all).

That said, it could well be related to the name ゆり**ひ**こ, which would be *Yurihiko* in standard romanization and could for example be written 百合彦 or 由利彦.

Indeed ～彦【ひこ】 *-hiko* is a [common suffix for a male name](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44536/1628) and [ひ *hi* is often mistaken for し *shi*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1437/1628).